# ansible set variable for another host

Tags: ansible

Please help set variable for another host:

For example:

```
---
- name: host1  - varaible from  vars_prompt
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
   - name: "host"
     prompt: "Enter host:"
     default: 'Aubuntu'

  tasks:
  - name:
    set_fact:
     monitip: "{{ansible_host}}"


- name: host2 - static host
  hosts: 'host2'

  tasks:
  - name: Добавляем в мониторинг
    shell: echo {{monitip}}
```

How to send `{{monitip}}` to host2 ?
I need get ip from host1 based on `vars_prompt {{ host }}` and use it in host2

```
fatal: [host2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'monitip' is undefined
```

**UPD:**

thanks for the replies, but I’m doing it all by myself by saving the variable to a file

```
---
- name: host1  - varaible from  vars_prompt
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
   - name: "host"
     prompt: "Enter host:"
     default: 'Aubuntu'

  tasks:

  - lineinfile : >
     dest=/tmp/s_ip.txt
     create=yes
     line='{{ansible_host}}'
    delegate_to: localhost


- name: host2 - static host
  hosts: 'host2'

  tasks:

  - command: cat /tmp/s_ip.txt
    register: monitip
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Добавляем в мониторинг
    shell: echo {{monitip.stdout}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the `hostvars` of the other host by name:

```
- hosts: host2
  tasks:
  - name: copy over monitip from the other host
    set_fact:
      monitip: '{{ hostvars[the_first_host].monitip }}'
    vars:
      the_first_host: '{{ groups.all | difference([inventory_hostname]) | first }}'
```

Of course, that won't work if `host2` represents a group of them, but that's the general idea, anyway

While that's the answer to your question, you are also likely jumping through a lot of hoops needlessly, since you can always access that hostvar directly, in the same playbook:

```
- hosts: host2
  vars_prompt:
  - # as before
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      monitip: '{{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}'
  # tada, drama free
```

Answer (score 0):

interesting request, I think I managed to get it working with slightly other approach.
Inventory file like for example:

```
$ cat inv
[myhosts]
host1.example.com
host2.example.com
```

and then a playbook like:

```
---
- hosts: myhosts
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "myhost"
      prompt: "Enter host:"
      default: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Use it
      debug:
        msg: "IP used on  {{ ansible_fqdn }} is {{ hostvars[myhost]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
      when: ansible_fqdn == myhost
```