# Ansible using dynamic variable on hosts returns Error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to create a playbook which basically consists 2 hosts init; (don't ask why)

```
---
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: get the hostname of machine and save it as a variable
        shell: hostname
        register: host_name
        when: ansible_host == "x.x.x.x" *(will be filled by my application)*
  - hosts: "{{ host_name.stdout }}"
    tasks:
      - name: use the variable as hostname
        shell: whoami
```

I don't have any hostname information in my application so I need to trigger my playbook with an IP address, then i should get the hostname of that machine and save it to a variable to use in my other tasks to avoid "when" command for each task.

The problem is that I'm able to use "host_name" variable in all other fields except "hosts", it gives me an Error like this when i try to run;

ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'host_name' is undefined

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSMD6.png)

Comment: My Ansible version is 2.9 and I'm aware of this fix; https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/38000

Comment: Because you have to look for it in the hostvars of the node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ansible set variable for another host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335450/ansible-set-variable-for-another-host)

Comment: I'm able to use this variable in other fields such as "name" or "shell" but it just doesn't let me to use it in "hosts" field. I don't think that my problem is related with hostvars.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Ansible itself gathers some information about a host. This happens at the beginning of a playbook's execution right after `PLAY` in `TASK [Gathering Facts]`.

*This automatic gathering of information about a system can be turned off via `gather_facts: no`, by default this is active.*

This collected information is called [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts). An example of the collected facts is shown in the [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts), for your host you can print out all Ansible Facts:

- either in the playbook as a task:

  ```yaml
  - name: Print all available facts
    debug:
      var: ansible_facts
  ```
- or via CLI as an adhoc command:

  ```
  ansible <hostname> -m setup
  ```

The Ansible Facts contain values like: `ansible_hostname`, `ansible_fqdn`, `ansible_domain` or even `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`. This is the simplest way to act with the hostname of the client.

If you want to output the hostname and IP addresses that Ansible has collected, you can do it with the following tasks for example:

```yaml
- name: Print hostname
  debug:
    var: ansible_hostname
- name: Print IP addresses
  debug:
    var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
```

---

If you start your playbook for all hosts, you can check the IP address and also stop it directly for the "wrong" clients.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: terminate execution for wrong hosts
      assert:
        that: '"x.x.x.x" is in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'
        fail_msg: Terminating because IP did not match
        success_msg: "Host matched. Hostname: {{ ansible_hostname }}"

    # your task for desired host
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The problem is that; Ansible doesn't let me to use dynamic variable in "hosts" even though it is a variable from Ansible facts or any.

Comment: Also i can't use the "assert" method because gather facts is taking so much time even more than using "when" condition for each task. For default I'm already using gather_facts: no